# Combinatorics - Two sets in Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, vba

Hard to explain this, but I will give it a go as I am stuck.

I am using NodeXL to look at the relationships in a dataset. Essentially I have some Topics and then Subtopics of those Topics, and I need a list of all the possible combinations of subtopics for each topic but only a maximum of two variables per combination (there will be duplication of combinations as there are multiple topics and I want to see which combinations are most common).

This is an example

Input:

```
Topic   Subtopic
G/xxx1   Banana
G/xxx1   Apple
G/xxx1   Pear
G/xxx1   Grape
G/xxx2   Banana
G/xxx2   Grape
G/xxx2   Pear
```

Output

```
A        B
Banana   Apple
Banana   Pear
Banana   Grape
Apple    Pear
Apple    Grape
Pear     Grape

Banana   Grape
Banana   Pear
Grape    Pear
```

I hope this makes sense and I would be very thankful if anyone has a good way of doing this. I cant do it manually as I have thousands of topics.

Comment: It looks like you're just trying to sort by column A, then column B.  You can subtotal in excel and see the total for groups, no VBA needed.

Comment: Looking at the Input versus Output, I"m not quite sure I'm understanding what you're going for (hence the above response giving what I think you meant) with the visual.  Given that A and B don't seem to really match up to the input, was A in output supposed to be the xxx1 and xxx2?  That's where i went with my first comment.

Comment: Hey Cyril, I think that Gauthier below has answered it, going to give it a try. What I was looking for was all the combinations for each topic, but I dont want to have the topic in the two columns. So essentially all combinations of two for each topic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this using a csv format, but you can probably tune it. How I would do it (using pandas to read the dataframe):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

combinations = []
for index, subset in df.groupby("Topic"):
    subtopics = list(subset["Subtopic"])
    n = len(subtopics)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            combinations.append(2(subtopics[i],subtopics[j]))

print combinations
print len(combinations)
```

In any case the best way to create all the pairs. I am working on a possible second solution. Will post it asap ;)

EDIT:

Here is my second solution (still using pandas):

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
indexedDF = df.reset_index().set_index("Topic")
mergedDF = pd.merge(indexedDF,indexedDF, left_index=True, right_index=True)
finalDF = mergedDF[mergedDF["index_x"] > mergedDF["index_y"]]

print finalDF
```

Comment: Hey Gauthier, going to give your method a try and will get back to you ASAP! :)..... thanks for your quick response

Comment: Thank you again, just quickly installing Python on my work computer so I can give it a go! :)

Comment: Hey Gauthier, couldnt get the first code to work, but got the second code to work perfectly. Thank you so much!! :)